# sql-maven-plugin with multiple delimiters

Tags: mysql, maven, sql-maven-plugin

I am using the sql-maven-plugin to execute some MySQL scripts on several databases.
I would like to deploy, in the same SQL script, tables, datas, triggers, events and stored procedures.

I have a problem with the line delimiter, because for INSERT or CREATE I use the `;`, but for my triggers I have to change the delimiter with `DELIMITER //`, for example.

I know that the plugin allows changing the delimiter, but it will be applicable for all the script, I want to change the delimiter only for a part of a unique script.

This is my maven configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.21</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
        <username>${db.user}</username>
        <password>${db.passwd}</password>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <orderFile>ascending</orderFile>
        <keepFormat>true</keepFormat>
        <driverProperties>characterEncoding=utf8,
                          connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci,
                          sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES</driverProperties>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>execution-mysql</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://${db.url}:${db.port}</url
                <delimiterType>normal</delimiterType>
                <fileset>
                    <basedir>${project.build.directory}/sql/</basedir>
                    <includes>
                        <include>${file.sql}</include>
                    </includes>
                </fileset>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
     </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set your delimeterType to "row" in configuration block.

```
<configuration>
...
   <delimiterType>row</delimiterType>
...
</configuration>
```

---

### delimiterType

> Normal means that any occurrence of the delimiter terminate the SQL
>   command whereas **with row, only a line containing just the delimiter is
>   recognized as the end of the command.**

See more at http://mojo.codehaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/execute-mojo.html#delimiterType

---

For examlpe: create-proc.sql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ADD_BOOK (IN title VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
   -- your sql code 
   INSERT INTO Book (title) VALUES (title);
END
; -- this means the end of the sql command
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my problem is that I have to create proc, tables and insert datas in only one SQL script, and I must start with USE `Database`, with this solution I can not run my USE `Database`.

Comment: It's OK now! I did not put every `;` on a new line. Many thanks!