# Error when executing mvn sql:execute

Tags: java, mysql, maven

I want Maven to execute the sql file, and the database schema it generates will be later used in my program. But it doesn't work, maybe caused by 'DELIMITER'. When I execute 'mvn sql:execute', it prints that

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute:  DELIMITER $$
```

Here is part of my pom.xml

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>  
            <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.21</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>init-schema</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>site</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                <username>root</username>
                <password>root</password>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8</url>
                <autocommit>false</autocommit>
                <srcFiles>
                    <srcFile>src/main/sql/jellyjolly-schema.sql</srcFile>
                </srcFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Here is part of my sql file

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `jellyjolly_schema`$$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `jellyjolly_schema`.`delete_user` $$
USE `jellyjolly_schema`$$


CREATE TRIGGER delete_user
AFTER DELETE
ON jj_users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    ## delete the posts that belong to the user
    DELETE FROM jj_blog_posts WHERE author_user_id=OLD.user_id;
END
$$
```

Is it because the keyword 'DELIMITER' is not supported by MySQL Java connector which is invoked by Maven. So how can I solve it?

Comment: Why are you using such a weird delimiter. The usual delimiter is ";".

Comment: @khmarbaise If i use delimiter ';', ';' cannot appear in declaim statement. For example, 'DELETE FROM jj_blog_posts WHERE author_user_id=OLD.user_id;' cannot end with ';'

Comment: I agree there is probably a more elegant solution. You could have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072354/sql-maven-plugin-with-multiple-delimiters) for inspiration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your comments, I believe the best solution is the one [accepted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072354/sql-maven-plugin-with-multiple-delimiters). That is, use only one delimiter (preferably the default, `;`) and use the `sql-maven-plugin` configuration to **require the delimiter to occur on it's own line** to actually be a delimiter.

```
    <configuration>
      <delimiterType>row</delimiterType>
    </configuration>
```

*(credit to @[Zheka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/794494/zheka))*

Your trigger would then look like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_user
AFTER DELETE
ON jj_users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    ## delete the posts that belong to the user
    DELETE FROM jj_blog_posts WHERE author_user_id=OLD.user_id; # this delimiter is ignored
END
; # this delimiter is recognized
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a new delimiter in the `sql-maven-plugin` configuration like so:

```
   <configuration>
     <delimiter>$$</delimiter>
   </configuration>
```

More on this configuration parameter at this [page](http://www.mojohaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/execute-mojo.html#delimiter).

Comment: If part of the sql use delimiter ; and another part use delimiter $$, how to handle it?

Comment: I don't believe it is possible, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

if yo u dont want to use `<delimiterType>row</delimiterType>` another way to do it besides sean's answer is to get rid of the  DELIMITER $$ and $$ and use a delimiter other than semicolon in the plugin.

First change the delimiter in the plugin, for example

```
<delimiter>;;</delimiter>
```

Then the example trigger above will look like

```
USE `jellyjolly_schema`;;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `jellyjolly_schema`.`delete_user`;;
USE `jellyjolly_schema`;;


CREATE TRIGGER delete_user
AFTER DELETE
ON jj_users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    ## delete the posts that belong to the user
    DELETE FROM jj_blog_posts WHERE author_user_id=OLD.user_id;
END;;
```

or you can use something else as the delimiter in the plugin and change the trigger ;; accordingly