# Postgresql trigger delimiter issue when creating test database via Maven

Tags: postgresql, maven, delimiter, sql-scripts

I am currently working on a Java application which uses a PostgreSQL database.  As part of the Maven build I test the database SQL scripts by dropping a test database, create it again and run all the SQL scripts.

On the Maven side I'm using the ["sql-maven-plugin"](http://www.mojohaus.org/sql-maven-plugin) plugin to execute these database commands and everything works nicely until I execute the `create_triggers.sql` script.  This is because there are semicolon characters (`;`) inside the trigger functions.  I've tried different things and my current (hacky) solution is to put set the `<delimiter>` of the *SQL Maven Plugin* to: -

```
<delimiter>;--</delimiter>
```

This specifies the delimiter as a semicolon immediately followed by a SQL comment.  This means I can run the `create_trigger.sql` script in both [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/) and via maven. e.g.

### create_scripts.sql

*(note the `;--` after each statement)*

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS refresh_updated_on_description ON my_table;--

/* Example trigger which updates `updated` field when `description` changes */

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION refresh_updated()  
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
   IF (NEW.description != OLD.description
   THEN
      NEW.updatedn = now(); 
      RETURN NEW;
   ELSE
      RETURN NEW;
   END IF;

END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';--

CREATE TRIGGER refresh_updated_on_description BEFORE UPDATE ON my_table FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE refresh_updated();--
```

### pom.xml

*(note the `<delimiter>;--</delimiter>` element in the last `<execution>` section)*
            ...

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                    <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                <username>${postgres.username}</username>
                <password>${postgres.password}</password>
                <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>drop-and-create-test-database</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals><goal>execute</goal></goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>${postgresql.test.db.server}</url>
                        <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                        <sqlCommand>
                            drop database if exists myapp_test;
                            create database myapp_test;
                        </sqlCommand>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>run-database-scripts-on-test-db</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals><goal>execute</goal></goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>${postgresql.test.db.database}</url>
                        <srcFiles>
                            <srcFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/sql/create_tables.sql</srcFile>
                        </srcFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>run-database-create-complex-scripts-on-test-db</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals><goal>execute</goal></goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>${postgresql.test.db.database}</url>
                        <delimiter>;--</delimiter>
                        <srcFiles>
                            <srcFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/sql/create_triggers.sql</srcFile>
                        </srcFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        ...
```

However, it feels like a hacky solution because I can only use the multi-line notation (`/*  some comment ... */`) for declaring comments in the `create_triggers.sql` file .  I also need to remember to include `;--` after each SQL statement as well in this file - otherwise the maven build will fail (but will run fine in pgAdmin).

Is there a better way to specify the delimiter inside the script?

Comment: Did you try to use "regular" single quotes instead of dollar-quoting? This does make maintaining the scripts a bit cumbersome, but should work even with Maven

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps the delimiter issue?

Comment: Because the parser will (should) see only a string constant and will (should) not consider delimiters inside a string constant.

Comment: OK, might be worth posting an answer to further illustrate what you mean.

Comment: As of 2019, my preferred approach now is to use Flyway to handle database scripts, so much better in every way.

Answer (score 0):

Ref this question: [Error when executing mvn sql:execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358978/error-when-executing-mvn-sqlexecute)

The solution says to change the config, so that the delimiter must be on its own row:

```
<delimiterType>row</delimiterType>
```

Then you end your function like this:

```
  end if;
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql'
;
```

and the parser keeps reading until it finds the semi-colon on the end.

You'll have to modify all your other sql statements to add a carriage return before each semicolon.